# How to create an SSL certificate for my demo server and access the client through "https" without any warning in browser

Tags: manual-testing, web-application, security-testing

I'm a QA guy working on a java based web application running on JBoss. The server is running on CentOS 6.6 (bash). When I access the client in a web browser from my PC through "https" (say https://10.0.0.1:8443) it says the connection is insecured. I further hit the "proceed anyway" link and access the client. Still in the URL address bar, the https is stroke out with a red line. I found that it is because the SSL certificate is not present. The following are the issues which did not get resolved after I googled it for a few hours.

1. Where do I create an SSL certificate? (I know i need to pass a few commands to the bash shell, but on which machine? The local machine or the machine in which my web server is running? )
2. What are the exact commands? A bit of explanation would be helpful.
3. Once the certificate is created (I think it will be something like certificate.ssl or some other format) where do I have to move it? Inside the application running? or leave it alone in the machine in which the server is running? Or keep it in my local machine?

Thanks. If you need any more information please ask in comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about server configuration and not SQA or testing. Please ask again on http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ssl

Answer (score 0):

1. SSL certificates need to be installed on the serverside, not the local machine
2. The exact commands differ per which web server software you are using

Have a look at [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) free certificates which they suggest you install with [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/). Certbot helps with commands and steps for each major web-server and operating system combination.

Also they have forums for getting further assistance: https://community.letsencrypt.org/